# How do I convert benzoic acid to m-nitrobenzyl alcohol using 2 steps?

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis

The question asks to carry out the following conversion in not more than 2 steps:

Benzoic acid to m-nitrobenzyl alcohol

I first used nitration (conc. $\ce{HNO3}$ /conc.$\ce{H2SO4}$) and then I'm got stuck, as reducing the $\ce{-COOH}$ group would also reduce $\ce{-NO2}$ group (using $\ce{LiAlH4}$).

I tried to reduce $\ce{-COOH}$ group using $\ce{LiAlH4}$ to $\ce{-CH2OH}$ and then proceed to nitration but got confused whether $\ce{-CH2OH}$ is o/p or m-directing. I think it should be o/p directing.

Comment: Then $\ce{-COOH}$ is meta directing. Does that solve your question? (think about a reducing agent with selective affinities)

Comment: @SatwikPasani I can't think of such a reagent which can reduce acid but not nitro...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Use the meta-directing effect of $\ce{-COOH}$: nitrate benzoic acid first.
2. Reduce *m*-nitrobenzoic acid with $\ce{LiAlH4}$. The nitro group is not attacked, but when you calculate the equivalents of  $\ce{LiAlH4}$ needed, don't forget that you are reacting an **acid** with a **hydride**.

---

**Edit 1**:
Nitroalkanes or nitroalkyl-substituted arenes can be converted to the corresponding amines by $\ce{LiAlH4}$. This is usually not the case for nitroarenes. Here, catalytic hydrogenation, e.g. over $\ce{Pd/C}$ is the method of choice.

**Edit 2**:
Let's play, change the order of events and first reduce benzoic acid to benzyl alcohol. The hydroxymethyl group isn't *m*-directing, but what will happen to it under nitration conditions ($\ce{H2SO4}$ and $\ce{HNO3}$)?

Under these pretty acidic conditions, elimination of water from the starting material furnishes benzyl cations, which might react with benzyl alcohol in different ways, such as (multiple) *Friedel-Crafts* alkylations or etherification. I'd dare to say that the result is a mess.

Comment: Wikipedia says that it will reduce nitro group. See reduction to amines. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduction_of_nitro_compounds

Comment: @Awesome Irrelevant in your case. Check out the link given in that article.

Comment: Oh right...Thanks. But please do tell whether $\ce{-CH2OH}$ is o/p directing or m-directing.

Comment: Isn't the hydroxymethyl substituent like a methyl group with a hydroxy group dangling from its far end? In electrophilic aromatic substitution, it's not m-directing. But would it survive treatment with sulfuric acid/nitric acid?

Comment: According to wikipedia $\ce{LiAlH4}$ and similar metal hydrides will reduce nitroarenes to azo compounds. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduction_of_nitro_compounds#Reduction_to_amines

Answer (score 2):

http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/jo00956a011

Required is a reduction that acts upon the carboxyl as such.  Consider borane-THF, or its equivalent sodium borohydride and BF3·Et2O.  Next best is borane-dimethyl sulfide, given the odor.  Aliphatic nitro groups are reduced.

Answer (score 0):

Use nitration by mixed acid and then $\ce{SOCl2}$ to replace the $\ce{OH}$ of carboxylic group. Then use $\ce{NaBH4}$ to reduce acid chloride to alcohol.

Comment: this is a three stage process not a two stage

Comment: bon is right. 2 steps, not three. Please study the question well before answering. That way the quality of the Q and A will be maintained.

Answer (score 0):

You were initially on the right track: 
After nitration with conc. HNO3 and conc. H2SO4, perform reduction with **Diborane (B2H6)**, under mild conditions as it does not easily reduce functional groups like nitro, halo, ester, etc. 
Voila, you have m-Nitrobenzyl alcohol.

Comment: If a reducing agent does not attack an ester, I’m having a hard time imagining it attacking an (even more stabilised) acid.